# Azure Content Moderator Portal - Unable to load Azure Media Services Video

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-media-services

We are creating video reviews in the [review tool](https://contentmoderator.cognitive.microsoft.com/) using the code [here](https://github.com/Abhith/VideoContentModerator) and everything used to work before (months back).
Now the only problem we are facing is loading the video on the review tool.

From the console, On chrome, it says CORB blocked the response,

> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://REDACTED.streaming.media.azure.net/REDACTED/ignite_c_c.ism/manifest with MIME type application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

[image]
And I can see 0B responses,

[image]

And on Firefox,
[image]

But if you paste the same video manifest URL in the [Azure Media Test Tool](https://openidconnectweb.azurewebsites.net/AMTestPlayer), it works fine there.

Any help to fix the video loading issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does KarthikBhyresh-MT's answer useful to you ? If yes, I will give him 100 reputation bounty.

Comment: The deprecation notice was news to me since it wasn't there when I posted this question. Anyway, I appreciate the help by Karthik for bringing that to my attention.

Answer (score -1):

If you say you were able to use tha same without any changes over months ago, maybe a browser update(unless you have updated endpoints or header to Cross site access policies). [Refer Configure CDN profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-portal-manage-streaming-endpoints#additional-considerations)

However, "CORB" referred above seems similar to CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing).

> It is an HTTP feature that enables a web application running under one
> domain to access resources in another domain. In order to reduce the
> possibility of cross-site scripting attacks, all modern web browsers
> implement a security restriction known as same-origin policy. This
> prevents a web page from calling APIs in a different domain. CORS
> provides a secure way to allow one origin (the origin domain) to call
> APIs in another origin.

CORS on Azure CDN will work automatically with no additional configuration. When you create a new account, default Streaming Endpoint Azure CDN integration is enabled by default. If you later want to disable/enable the CDN, your streaming endpoint must be in the stopped state. It could take up to two hours for the Azure CDN integration to get enabled and for the changes to be active across all the CDN POPs.

you might want to start using a wildcard (*) to setup the HTTP header, which disables CORS and allows any URL to access the CDN Endpoint.

Refer: [Using Azure CDN with CORS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-cors)

```
Caution: The Content Moderator Review tool is now deprecated and will be retired on 12/31/2021.
```

Video moderation enables detection of potential adult content in videos. The review tool internally calls the automated moderation APIs and presents the items for review right within your web browser

There are multiple indications:

- SameSite cookie flag error
- No decoders for requested formats
- CORB error

You can give this a try though:

Set the SameSite by default cookies flag value to Disabled in Chrome 80 and later versions.

```
In your Chrome browser session, address chrome://flags/ and Search for or find the flag, SameSite by default cookies.
Select Disabled
```

.

Comment: The deprecation notice was news to me. Before I posted this question, I was looking into the docs and all but never seen that. 
Since the review tool is deprecated, there is no point in chasing for the right answer. Appreciate your help.